# Disable dbutils.fs.put() write to console "Wrote x bytes"

Tags: dbutils

does anyone know how to suppress the output of dbutils.fs.put() ?

write dbutils.fs.put('abfs://some_address_to_some_abfs_location_you_have/helloworld.txt','Hello World',True) and notice that it outputs "Wrote X bytes." to the console stdout. I don't want "Wrote X bytes" to be written to the console.